# Looping multiple single song audio players for continuous play

Tags: javascript, html, mp3, jplayer, ogg

I am trying to link audio players so that when one finishes, the next song will start playing. I will have an endless number of players, so I am wondering how to do this. This is pretty straight forward code. Here is an example of two songs:

```
<div class="container">
<!-- DJ Picture -->
<img src="Pictures/Calvinharris.jpg" class="img1" />
        <div class="box">
        <!-- DJ Name -->
        <span class="bigroom">Calvin Harris</span>

        <!-- Song Title -->
        <h2>We Found Love (Chuckie Mix)</h2>

         <!--Song Description(179 characters with spaces)-->
        <h4>Beautiful, pounding piano stabs combined with great vocals make this                            track a phenomenal one. Manages to powerfully fill a massive sound-space without sounding cluttered.</h4> 
                <!--Song file info-->
            <div class="player">
        <body><a id="m12" class="audio  {skin:'#010101',showVolumLevel:false,showTime:false,ogg:'MP3/Rihanna feat. Calvin Harris - We Found Love (Chuckie Extended Mix).ogg'}" href="MP3/Rihanna feat. Calvin Harris - We Found Love (Chuckie Extended Mix).mp3"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<!-- DJ Picture -->
<img src="Pictures/dirtyharris.jpg" class="img1" />
        <div class="box">
        <!-- DJ Name -->
        <span class="techno"> ThreeSixty & Dirty Harris</span>

        <!-- Song Title -->
        <h2>Louka (Funkagenda Re-Edit)</h2>

         <!--Song Description(179 characters with spaces)-->
        <h4>I had to include this one since it literally took over control of me while driving the other morning. I was bouncing around in my seat like a little kid who desparately needs to use the bathroom. </h4> 

            <!--Song file info-->
            <div class="player">
        <body><a id="m11" class="audio {skin:'#010101',showVolumLevel:false,showTime:false,ogg:'MP3/ThreeSixty, Funkagenda - Loudka (Funkagenda Re-Edit).ogg'}" href="MP3/ThreeSixty, Funkagenda - Loudka (Funkagenda Re-Edit).mp3"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the jquery I have come up with, but it does not work.

```
function playNext(idx){
var players=$(".audio");
document.playerIDX = idx+1 <= players.length-1 ? idx+1 : 0;
players.eq(document.playerIDX).mb_miniPlayer_play();
}
```

Comment: you resolved this problem yet?

Answer (score 1):

Use the playlist add-on:

http://www.jplayer.org/latest/demo-02-jPlayerPlaylist/

Works fine on my side